# Vertical Scroll bar goes away after Razorpay payment is Success or Razorpay Modal is Closed in Angular

Tags: css, angular, razorpay

When I open any bootstrap modal on my page, The Overflow of the body is hidden and When I close the modal, The Overflow is Visible. This is the Correct Way.

But For RazorPay, When I open the payment modal, the overflow is hidden, but after making the payment or closing the payment modal without payment, The Overflow does not become visible.
I couldn't scroll the page, I need to refresh the page to make it work.

The solution which I have tried so far:

1. I added overflow: auto to the body tag of the main CSS file. The problem was, The Overflow was not hidden when I open the modal.
2. I tried the below code, what it does is, on both payment success or payment window close, overflow: auto will be added to the body. But the problem was when I open the modal the second time, the overflow is not getting hidden. It always stays visible.

   ```js
   handler: function (response) {
             $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
           },
    modal: {
             ondismiss: function () {
               $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
             },
           },
   ```
3. to make the overflow hidden again, I have to add $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden') in all places where I have a modal button or else I have to refresh the page to make it work again normal, But it doesn't have good user experience to refresh the page each time.

is there a best way to achieve this?
I checked the Razorpay doc page, But I couldn't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Added this to styles.css and now it's working fine.

```
body {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: I already tried this. But the problem is, Overflow is always visible when the above property is added. By default, When we open Boostrap Modal, Overflow will be hidden, When we close Modal, Overflow will appear. This behaviour is not happening with Razorpay. I have many Bootstrap modal on my page which is affecting due to this property.

Comment: Make use of  encapsulation to limit the scope of CSS.
https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

In your RazorPay Options add this

```
modal:{
  ondismiss: function(){
    document.body.style = '';
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's wrong you can not override style since it read only so correct method is
document.body.style.overflow=''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is my Solution.
add this style to global css.

```
.scroll-y {
 overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

then add this in constructor,

```
constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document){}
```

then, Instead of using traditional function, We need to use arrow function. so that, we can access 'this'

```
modal: {
    ondismiss: () => {         
        this.document.body.classList.add('scroll-y');
    },
},
```